# JTree File Filter and Folder Filter

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I want to have a JTree which display's all the files with only ".h" extension in my current directory, and it should display all the folders, except a folder named 'System Volume Information', in my current directory, here's my code, what addition.. updation i need to do ??

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;


public class DriveTree extends JPanel
{

    public DriveTree(File dir) 
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTree tree = new JTree(addNodes(null, dir));
        add(tree);
    }

    DefaultMutableTreeNode addNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode curTop, File dir)
    {
        String curPath = dir.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode curDir = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(curPath);
        if (curTop != null)
        {
          curTop.add(curDir);
        }
        Vector ol = new Vector();
        String[] tmp = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
        ol.addElement(tmp[i]);
        Collections.sort(ol, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        File f;
        Vector files = new Vector();
        for (int i = 0; i < ol.size(); i++)
        {
            String thisObject = (String) ol.elementAt(i);
            String newPath;
            if (curPath.equals("."))
            newPath = thisObject;
            else
            newPath = curPath + File.separator + thisObject;
            if ((f = new File(newPath)).isDirectory())
            addNodes(curDir, f);
            else
            files.addElement(thisObject);
        }
       for (int fnum = 0; fnum < files.size(); fnum++)
       curDir.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(files.elementAt(fnum)));
       return curDir;
    }

  public static void main(String[] av)
  {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drive View");
    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
    if (av.length == 0) 
    {
      cp.add(new DriveTree(new File(".")));
    }
    else
    {
      cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cp, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
      for (int i = 0; i < av.length; i++)
      cp.add(new DriveTree(new File(av[i])));
    }
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what's wrong with your code, for starters.  What does it do that you do not expect, or not do that you DO expect, or what?

Comment: See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of the API.  The `File` class provides the ability to filter the returned results from the `list` method...

```
File[] file = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        String name = pathname.getName().toLowerCase();
        return name.endsWith(".h") || (pathname.isDirectory() && !("System Volume Information".equalsIgnoreCase(name)));
    }
});
```

**Updated with example**

As near as I can tell, this is what your looking for.  This may change the result on the screen, as I'm using the `File` object directly, but it can be fixed by using a [`TreeCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class DriveTree extends JPanel {

    public DriveTree(File dir) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTree tree = new JTree(addNodes(null, dir));
        add(tree);
    }

    DefaultMutableTreeNode addNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode curTop, File dir) {
        String curPath = dir.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode curDir = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(curPath);
        if (curTop != null) {
            curTop.add(curDir);
        }

        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                String name = pathname.getName().toLowerCase();
                return name.endsWith(".h") || (pathname.isDirectory() && !("System Volume Information".equalsIgnoreCase(name)));
            }
        })));

        Collections.sort(files);
//        File f;
//        Vector files = new Vector();
//        for (int i = 0; i < ol.size(); i++) {
//            String thisObject = (String) ol.elementAt(i);
//            String newPath;
//            if (curPath.equals(".")) {
//                newPath = thisObject;
//            } else {
//                newPath = curPath + File.separator + thisObject;
//            }
//            if ((f = new File(newPath)).isDirectory()) {
//                addNodes(curDir, f);
//            } else {
//                files.addElement(thisObject);
//            }
//        }
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                addNodes(curDir, file);
            }
        }
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                curDir.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file));
            }
        }
        return curDir;
    }

    public static void main(String[] av) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drive View");
        Container cp = frame.getContentPane();
        if (av.length == 0) {
            cp.add(new DriveTree(new File(".")));
        } else {
            cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cp, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            for (int i = 0; i < av.length; i++) {
                cp.add(new DriveTree(new File(av[i])));
            }
        }
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried it..not getting it to work..i may be asking for too much..but can you pleas..add up your segment in my code as exactly one should ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:304)
 at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
 at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:916)
 at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
 at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
 at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:799)
 at Arrears.DriveTree$1.accept(DriveTree.java:44)at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1217)at Arrears.DriveTree.addNodes(DriveTree.java:40)
at Arrears.DriveTree.addNodes(DriveTree.java:53)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the extension of the File you want to add and do an examination onto this extension:

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1) {
    extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}

if(extension.equals("h"))
{
   //Add to your tree
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a FileNameExtensionFilter

```
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(null, "h");

for(//...
    if ((f = new File(newPath)).isDirectory())
        addNodes(curDir, f);
    else if(filter.accept(new File(newPath))) //accept only returns true if the extension matches
        files.addElement(thisObject);
```